Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" in Neo4J
After executing this code to create  a vctor index
    CREATE VECTOR INDEX movie_tagline_embeddings IF NOT EXISTS
      FOR (m:Movie)
      ON (m.taglineEmbedding)
      OPTIONS { 
        indexConfig: {
          'vector.dimensions': 1536,
          'vector.similarity_function': 'cosine'
        }
      }

I run into following error:
Invalid input '{': expected "+" or "-" (line 5, column 18 (offset: 131))
"    indexConfig: {"
^
Any ideas? Iam new to Neo4j and can't get it solved

From the documentation You can see the example for the key of the indexConfig it is using ` instead of single quote.
CREATE VECTOR INDEX `abstract-embeddings`
FOR (n: Abstract) ON (n.embedding)
OPTIONS {indexConfig: {
 `vector.dimensions`: 1536,
 `vector.similarity_function`: 'cosine'
}}

